# How can I display flash messages with devise using Semantic-UI in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, semantic-ui, ruby-on-rails-4.2

For learning purpose I have created a user model with devise gem and for styling I am using semantic-ui. How can I display flash messages with semantic-ui styling in devise when user logs in or logs out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display flash messages, create a method in application helper, to find out the type of flash message, something like this,

```
def flash_class(type)
 case type
  when "success" then "ui green message"
  #add in the other options and the styles for it.
 end
end
```

And then in views, add

```
<% flash.each do |key, value|%>
<div class="<%= flash_class(key) %> closable">
<i class = "close icon"></i>
<%= value %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Add styles for the class 
.message.closable{
}

For further details please check this link https://coderwall.com/p/7gqmog/display-flash-messages-with-semantic-ui-in-rails. A detailed explanation available here.

Comment: you will have to edit the devise views as the above specified view.

Comment: Have you installed the devise views in your application? if so then like any rails view file, you can make changes in devise views too for reflecting the semantic UI.